# Laravel: set default timestamp to one year from now

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I've seen a few threads on how to set the default of a timestamp column to the current datetime using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. However, I am looking for how to set the default to the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 year.

I tried this but didn't have any success:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->timestamp('expires')->default(DB::raw('NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR'))->after('updated_at');
});
```

Received this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ INTERVAL 1
>   YEAR after `updated_at`' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `users`
>   add `expires` timestamp not null default NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR after
>   `updated_at`)
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ INTERVAL 1
>   YEAR after updated_at' at line 1

Any idea on how to set the default for this column to be the one year from the current date?

Comment: Would this perhaps be better handled by `PHP`? When inserting a new record, set `$newRecord->expires = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addYears(1);`, as a quick example.

Comment: @TimLewis That is definitely the alternative option - was just wondering if there was a way to set a default directly with the create statement.

Comment: You can't do in the dafult value of timestamp field - have a look at mysql docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html. You can only set the default to current timestamp or have it auto-updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could let the database handle it all by creating a trigger.

**create table/insert table/create trigger**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS stackoverflow;
USE stackoverflow;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  , user_name VARCHAR(255)  
  , expires DATETIME 
); 


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS users_expires;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER users_expires BEFORE INSERT
    ON users
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF NEW.expires IS NULL 
       THEN 
        SET NEW.expires = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR;   
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name) VALUES ('raymond nijland')
```

**Result**

```
Query: INSERT INTO users (user_name) VALUES ('raymond nijland')

1 row(s) affected
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

**Result**

```
    id  user_name        expires              
------  ---------------  ---------------------
     1  raymond nijland  2018-11-06 18:50:16
```